# Recording from two webcamera into one

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG I am trying to record a video which will have input from two cameras. In output video I want input of camera side by side for this I have used `hstack`:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 200M -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -f dshow -i video="USB2.0 Camera" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v];" -map "[v]" -f flv test.flv
```

But I am getting an error as:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 200M -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -rtbufsize 200M -f dshow -i video="USB2.0 Camera" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]" -map "[v]" -f flv test.flv
```

`rtbufsize` is an input option and has to be applied to each input for which it is intended.

The final filter in a filter_complex should not be terminated with a delimiter (`,` or `;`).